# VB.Net Declare an array of classes, and set value

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, class

I have a little syntax declare problem in VB.Net.

```
Dim proxy As USImportoerServiceTypeClient = DMRUtils.CreateAndConfigureClient()

Dim request As New USDeclare_I()
request.DeclareCollection = New US_ITypeDeclare() {}
For Each KES In request.DeclareCollection
    KES.DeclareCollectionStructure.DeclareCollectionValidDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDeclareDate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat)
Next
```

This above code do not work, becase the **"US_ITypeDeclare() {}"** is empty an only contains a new DeclareCollectionStructure

How do I declare a KoeretoejErklaeringStructure to this an set this date value til
"DeclareCollectionStructure.DeclareCollectionValidDate" ?

Best regards from Denmark

Comment: You are trying to `For Each` over the array, but the array is empty.  Where are the objects suppose to be coming from?

Comment: Aside from very specific uses to their advantage, arrays are a rather clumsy and antiquated way of storing and managing information in .NET.  Perhaps lists or collections would better suit this application.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays have a fixed length, which is declared when the array is created. Therefore your array will always have a length of `0`.

Use a `List(Of T)` instead. Lists grow dynamically when you add items to them.

```
request.DeclareCollection = New List(Of US_ITypeDeclare)
Dim newItem = new US_ITypeDeclare()
newItem.DeclareCollectionStructure.DeclareCollectionValidDate =  _
    DateTime.ParseExact(txtDeclareDate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", _
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat)
request.DeclareCollection.Add(newItem)
' Now the list contains one item
```

Of cause you will have to adapt the definition of `DeclareCollection` to be a list instead of an array.

Comment: Thank you very much, Oliver.
I think we are close to a solution, but there is a litlle issue in the first line.
request.DeclareCollection = New List(of US_ITypeDeclare) is not walid an in the error tooltip is says: "Cannot be converted to a 1-dimentional array of US_ITypeDeclare", maybe becase the US_ITypeDeclare is an multi-array of classes, as defined above.

Comment: PLEASE HELP ... If posible. :-)

Comment: As I said, you will have to change `DeclareCollection` to be a list. `Public DeclareCollection As List(Of US_ITypeDeclare)`. Another option is to keep the array but initialize it with a constant length of one (it's hard to say from here) `Dim newItem = new US_ITypeDeclare(1)`